# SetTimeout and recursivity with cucumber

Tags: javascript, settimeout, cucumberjs

I have a function written in javascript calling itself in a recursive way :

```
function f(attempt){
    if (attempt + 1 <= 10) {
        setTimeout(f(attempt + 1),2000);
    }
}
f(0);
```

For an unknown reason the function is effectively called 10 times but without any delay. The setTimeout seems to execute immediately the function f.

However when I do this then everything works fine :

```
function f(attempt){
if (attempt + 1 < 10) {
    setTimeout(function(){f(attempt + 1);},2000);
}}
f(0);
```

Do you have an explanation ? Is is because this code is written for Cucumber testing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass the function as a parameter to `setTimeout`, that means no parenthesis at the end of `f`. What you are doing right now is calling `f` and passing it's return value to `setTimeout`. You can pass arguments to `f` as the third argument of `setTimeout`. Your call should look like this:

```
setTimeout(f, 2000, attempt + 1);
```

Comment: Ok, so is it normal that the function is still called but without delay ?

Comment: Yes, because you explicitly call it with your `f(attempt + 1)`. As described above: You don't need to pass a function *call* (with parenthesis), only the function's name.

Answer (score 2):

```
setTimeout(f(attempt + 1),2000);
```

This code above calls setTimeout function and instead of passing a function to call it passes the result of your f() function, it is invoked right on the spot.

```
  setTimeout(function() { f(attempt + 1) },2000);
```

But in this case you are passing a reference to your function to be invoked in a 2000 seconds, so it does not evaluate the function itself on the spot.

Answer (score 0):

You should write it like this.
This is an alternative way to do the check and have no private vars.

```
function f(){
 if(++attempt<10){// not shure 
  setTimeout(f,2000);
 }
}
var attempt=0;
f();
```

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/3nm2Q/